# Insert customer id into unrelated table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert

I have a table with customer ids. I need to associate them with response ids loaded from a text file. I'm bulk loading the external file into a temporary table but I don't know how to associate them with the customer ids.

I'm starting with these two tables:

**Recipient**

```
+------+------------+------------+
|  id  | CustomerId | ResponseId |
+------+------------+------------+
|   1  |       1001 |    NULL    |
|  19  |       2367 |    NULL    |
|  47  |        964 |    NULL    |
| 105  |       1811 |    NULL    |
+------+------------+------------+
```

**#Responses**

```
+--------+
|   id   |
+--------+
| ABCDEF |
| GHIJKL |
| MNOPQR |
| STUVWX |
+--------+
```

And I'm looking to get something like the following:

**Recipient**

```
+------+------------+------------+
|  id  | CustomerId | ResponseId |
+------+------------+------------+
|   1  |       1001 |   ABCDEF   |
|  19  |       2367 |   STUVWX   |
|  47  |        964 |   MNOPQR   |
| 105  |       1811 |   GHIJKL   |
+------+------------+------------+
```

The matching order between `CustomerId` and `ResponseId` is unimportant (I've shown them in a different sort order to the `#Responses` table) as long as each id from `#Responses` is associated with one `CustomerId`.

The `#Responses` table will be guaranteed to have at least as many rows as the `Recipient` table.

In case it matters, I'm using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Why does `Customer` have an `id` *and* a `CustomerId`?

Comment: Poor choice of table name. The table should be called Recipient. I'll edit the question

Comment: If it doesn't matter about matching id's why dont you just insert them from the temp table into the table with customer id's?

Comment: How would inserting help? That would create more rows. When I tried using an update all my ResponseId values were the same as the first row in the #Responses table.

Comment: @sixeyes: OK, but I still don't understand the need for `id`. What do you use it for?

Comment: It's an identity field and it's the primary key for the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case you can use the row_number() at both the places and do the join

```
;WITH Cust AS
(
 SELECT row_number() over(order by (select 1)) rn,* FROM Customer
),Resp AS
(
  SELECT row_number() over(order by (select 1)) rn,* FROM #Responses
)
SELECT C.id,c.CustomerID,C.ResponseId 
FROM Cust C 
JOIN Resp R 
ON C.rn = R.rn
```

Comment: Thank you. However it would appear I oversimplified my problem. I'm using a select to retrieve my rows from the Recipient (formerly Customer) table, so my row numbers aren't sequential. Is there an easy fix for this? I've edit the question to show my problem more clearly.

Comment: My colleague has just pointed out I can put a WHERE clause in the WITH so it's all sorted. Thanks for your help.